# How to sync folder contents between Android phone and wearable using Bluetooth?

Tags: flutter, file, synchronization

I am trying to sync folders contents between two devices (one wearable and one Android phone) connected through Bluetooth. Each device has one folder that needs to be updated with the files on the other device (both directions), it means copying a new file found on that folder or updating based on timestamp.

I need this operation to occur without any internet connection, just the Bluetooth connection between the two devices.

Since I'm new to Flutter, I couldn't find any API for this.
Any help is very much appreciated!